# Cleaner SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that are joined using foreign key, example: budget_items table column "id" and transactions tables column "parent_id"

Each table has some similar column names such as name and date for example. So when I query the table I'm pulling the data out as follows:

```
SELECT
                        budget_items.id AS BI_id,
                        budget_items.owner_id as BI_owner,
                        budget_items.name AS BI_name, 
                        budget_items.date AS BI_date,
                        budget_items.amount AS BI_amount,
                        budget_items.type AS BI_type,
                        transactions.id as TRANS_id, 
                        transactions.parent_id as TRANS_parent,
                        transactions.owner_id as TRANS_owner,
                        transactions.amount as TRANS_amount,
                        transactions.date as TRANS_date,
                        transactions.type as TRANS_type,
                        transactions.processed as TRANS_processed,
                        transactions.name AS TRANS_name 
                    FROM
                        myezbudget.budget_items budget_items,
                        myezbudget.transactions transactions
                    WHERE
                        budget_items.id = transactions.parent_id AND
                        budget_items.owner_id = ?`, [req.user.id]
```

My question would be, is there a better way to do this with a more concise query? I tried with a few different types of join statements but couldn't get it to output the way I liked. I'm by no means a SQL expert and would appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: The answers below are valid (thus far), but in terms of performance, what matters is indexes - in this case an index on budget_items(owner_id) and transactions(parent_id)

Comment: I have both of those set as indexes at this time. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You can fix the query to use proper `join` syntax and table aliases.  However, you will still need to alias each column independently, which is what I think your real question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

- Use modern `JOIN` syntax.
- Use shorter table aliases.

The query should look like:

```
SELECT
    i.id AS BI_id,
    i.owner_id as BI_owner,
    i.name AS BI_name, 
    i.date AS BI_date,
    i.amount AS BI_amount,
    i.type AS BI_type,
    t.id as TRANS_id, 
    t.parent_id as TRANS_parent,
    t.owner_id as TRANS_owner,
    t.amount as TRANS_amount,
    t.date as TRANS_date,
    t.type as TRANS_type,
    t.processed as TRANS_processed,
    t.name AS TRANS_name 
FROM myezbudget.budget_items i
JOIN myezbudget.transactions t on i.id = t.parent_id 
WHERE i.owner_id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this option, it does make for less typing and more concise names. Is there a particular benefit to using the JOIN vs what I was doing in my example, other than that is correct syntax and standard? Just curious if performance wise it is better to use "JOIN"

Comment: The modern join syntax makes a clear difference between join conditions (in the `JOIN` clause) and filtering conditions (in the `WHERE` clause). This makes the SQL easier to understand and to debug. Other than that, there's no performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use an inner join instead of selecting two tables in the `FROM` statement and linking them together in the `WHERE` by doing it like this:

```
SELECT
    budget_items.id AS BI_id,
    budget_items.owner_id as BI_owner,
    budget_items.name AS BI_name, 
    budget_items.date AS BI_date,
    budget_items.amount AS BI_amount,
    budget_items.type AS BI_type,
    transactions.id as TRANS_id, 
    transactions.parent_id as TRANS_parent,
    transactions.owner_id as TRANS_owner,
    transactions.amount as TRANS_amount,
    transactions.date as TRANS_date,
    transactions.type as TRANS_type,
    transactions.processed as TRANS_processed,
    transactions.name AS TRANS_name 
FROM
    myezbudget.budget_items budget_items,
INNER JOIN myezbudget.transactions AS transactions ON budget_items.id = transactions.parent_id
WHERE
    budget_items.owner_id = ?`, [req.user.id]
```

You could always try shortening the table aliases as well to make them more compact but if you want them descriptive then that's fine. Also when the column only exists in one table then you don't have to specify the table name all of the time, however I would say this is personal preference.

Comment: When using a real `JOIN` putting the join conditions on the `WHERE` part becomes unnecesary. Just leave the last line on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Alejandro that is because I just copied and pasted and forgot to delete that line! Thanks for that spot, I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was afraid that there wouldn't necessarily be a way to shorten this query considering the way I use this data after the query resulting in the need for the descriptive tags.